# how to convert java to ruby

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, encryption, aes

I am trying to convert some code from java to ruby but its not working properly.I am trying to encrypt a string in ruby using Cipher with AES algorithm

```
public String encryptData(String data, String requestorId, String encryptionKey) throws  InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,NoSuchPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException
{
    String encryptedData = data;
    SecretKey secretKey1 = secretKeyGeneration(requestorId, encryptionKey,"AES", 256);
    byte[] encrytedString1 = encrypt(secretKey1, data);
    encryptedData = StringUtil.fromByteArrayToBase64(encrytedString1);      
    return encryptedData;
}

 public static SecretKey secretKeyGeneration(String requestor, String key, String algo, Integer size)
{
    NAPISecretKey napiSecretKey = new NAPISecretKey();
    napiSecretKey.setAlgorithm(algo);
    napiSecretKey.setKey(StringUtil.fromByteArrayToBase64((key).getBytes()));
    napiSecretKey.setSize(size);
    return decodeSecretKey(napiSecretKey.getKey(), napiSecretKey.getAlgorithm());
}

public static SecretKey decodeSecretKey(String key, String algo)
{
    if ("AES".equals(algo)) {
        return new SecretKeySpec(StringUtil.fromBase64ToByteArray(key), algo);}
    else {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException(algo + " is not supported");}
}

public class NAPISecretKey {
    private String  algorithm;  
    private int size;
    private String  key;
    public String getAlgorithm() {
        return algorithm;}
    public void setAlgorithm(String algorithm) {
    this.algorithm = algorithm;}
    public int getSize() {
    return size;}
    public void setSize(int size) {
    this.size = size;}
    public String getKey() {
    return key;}
    public void setKey(String key) {
    this.key = key;}
}

public static byte\[\] encrypt(SecretKey secretKey, String plaintext) throws InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException,
BadPaddingException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException
{
    return encrypt(secretKey, StringUtil.fromStringToByteArray(plaintext));
}
public static byte\[\] encrypt(SecretKey secretKey, byte\[\] plaintext) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException,IllegalBlockSizeException,BadPaddingException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException
{
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, new IvParameterSpec(new byte\[16\]));
    return cipher.doFinal(plaintext);
}

import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.Base64.Decoder;
import java.util.Base64.Encoder;

public class StringUtil {
    private static  Charset charset;
    private StringUtil() {
        super();
    }
    static {
        charset=Charset.forName("UTF-8");
    }
    public  static  byte[]  fromBase64ToByteArray(String data) {
        Decoder decoder=Base64.getDecoder();
        return  decoder.decode(fromStringToByteArray(data));
    }
    public  static  String  fromByteArrayToBase64(byte[]    data) {
        Encoder encoder=Base64.getEncoder();
        return  encoder.encodeToString(data);
    }
    public  static  byte[]  fromStringToByteArray(String data) {
        return  data.getBytes(charset);
    }
    public  static  String  fromByteArrayToString(byte[] data) {
        return  new String(data,charset);
    }
}
```

the ruby code is

```
def encrypt_data
      encryption_key="12345678"
      requestor_id="IN000000"
      encrypted_data = params[:orderReqDtls] || request.headers[:orderReqDtls]
      encrypted_data = @order_data if caller_locations.any? { |loc| loc.label == 'generate_json_order_data' }
      secret_key = secret_key_generation(requestor_id, encryption_key, "AES", 256)
      encrypted_string = encrypt(secret_key, encrypted_data)
      encrypted_data = Base64.strict_encode64(encrypted_string)
      return render json: {data:encrypted_data}
    end

    def secret_key_generation(requestor, key, algo, size)
      napi_secret_key = NAPISecretKey.new
      napi_secret_key.algorithm = algo
      base64_encoded_key = ""
      key.bytes.each do |i|
        base64_encoded_key+=i.to_s
      end
      napi_secret_key.key = from_byte_array_to_base64(base64_encoded_key)
      napi_secret_key.size = size
      return decode_secret_key(napi_secret_key.key,napi_secret_key.algorithm )
    end

    def decode_secret_key(key, algo)
      if algo == "AES"
        decodedKey = Base64.decode64(key)
      else
        raise "#{algo} is not supported"
      end
    end

    def encrypt(secret_key, plaintext)
      text=""
      plaintext.bytes.each do |i|
        text+=i.to_s
      end
      cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new('AES-256-ECB')
      cipher.encrypt
      cipher.key = secret_key
      cipher.iv = "\0" * 16
      encrypted_data = cipher.update(plaintext) + cipher.final
    end
```

the output encrypted code is different for both the cases for any given output.can you suggest me the changes in ruby to get the same output

Comment: secret_key_generation method looks suspect. why are you building a string of integers and passing to from_byte_array_to_base64

Comment: I am trying to get exact output like java.In order to get the output like StringUtil.fromByteArrayToBase64((key).getBytes())) I used the do loop.I tried without do loop also but it also failed

Comment: A string of concatenated integers is not an array -- will never work as you expect.  Need to work through step by step.